# Tkinter Class usage- object() takes no parameters? (WARNING- EXTREME BEGINNER)

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So I have lifted this code straight from the book: Programming the Raspberry Pi; Getting started with Python by Simon Monk:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:

    def _init_(self,master):
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack
        Label(frame, text='deg C').grid(row=0, column=0)
        button = Button(frame, text='Convert', command=self.convert)
        button.grid(row=1)

    def convert(self):
        print('Not implemented ')

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Temp Conv')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However, when I run it it returns the error that

```
line 18, in <module>
    app = App(root)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need 2 _ marks before and after **init**

Thats the format recognized by python as the **init** function.  since you only put 1 before and after its not recognizing the "**init**" correctly and thinks its a user created function named "*init*".  Which means the program thinks there isn't a "**init**"specified therefore no parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a dream.